# Ajuste de cor do texto em temas diferentes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Trabalho na manutenção de um sistema que só podia ser exibido com o fundo branco, e recentemente adotamos a possibilidade de o usuário escolher o fundo escuro.

Alguns campos de texto são guardados com formatação no banco de dados, sendo assim caso a cor do texto formatado seja preto a exibição fica comprometida.

Há alguma forma de melhorar a exibição desses textos formatados com cor preta no fundo escuro?

Procuro alguma biblioteca javascript ou compatível com asp.net para fazer a adequação das cores.

## Edit

Segue um exemplo de como os dados são salvos no banco:

```html
<p class="CorpodoTexto">&nbsp;</p>
 <p class="CorpodoTexto">Todo e qualquer retrabalho &eacute; desnecess&aacute;rio e causa perda
 de tempo, v&ecirc;-se logo ao analisar a palavra. Com foco em evitar o retrabalho e
 perda de tempo, foi criada a API . Tendo em sua primeira vers&atilde;o a
 finalidade de disponibilizar a lista de produtos cadastrada em nosso ERP, bem
 como, a possibilidade de inserir atrav&eacute;s de servi&ccedil;o, pedidos no j&aacute; mencionad<span style="color: #000000;">o
 ERP.</span></p>
 <p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Este
 documento especifica alguns dos principais requisitos da API .
 Sua cria&ccedil;&atilde;o se deu para auxiliar desenvolvedores, fornecendo as informa&ccedil;&otilde;es
 necess&aacute;rias para a implementa&ccedil;&atilde;o de uma integra&ccedil;&atilde;o coerente e pr&aacute;tica.</span></p>
 <p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As
 demais se&ccedil;&otilde;es apresentam as especifica&ccedil;&otilde;es da API </span>e est&atilde;o organizadas da
 seguinte forma:</p>
 <p class="CorpodoTexto" style="margin-left: 36pt; text-indent: -18pt;"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </span></span><!--[endif]--><strong>Se&ccedil;&atilde;o 2 &ndash;
 Classes para a comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o:</strong> Descreve o formato das classes de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o
 bem como as tipagens e obrigatoriedades de seus atributos.</p>
 <strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Se&ccedil;&atilde;o
 3 &ndash; Servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis:</span></strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"> Descreve
 os servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis na vers&atilde;o corrente da API  bem como um
 exemplo passo&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';"></span>
```

Comment: Cores, tamanhos de fonte, entre outros, se trata com `CSS`

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta alguns exemplos da formatação que vem do banco para uma melhor análise.

Comment: @sam inseri um exemplo que peguei direto do banco

Comment: @Pilati acabei de editar minha resposta vale a pena tu dar uma executada e analisada no meu código e tentar adaptar para o seu.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer a mudança das cores/fontes das letras por css.

No seu código js, quando o usuário chamar a função que troca a cor do fundo, serão executados os comandos para a mudança do tema, nessa mesma função coloque comandos css para fazer a troca da cor das letras.

Ou caso não queira fazer isso, pode mudar a cor padrão da fonte para um cinza, que combinaria com o preto e o branco, dando destaque em ambos!

Abraço, qualquer duvida estou a disposição!

Comment: Colocar uma cor intermediária não seria uma opção, posso colocar um cinza, mas e se o texto for cinza? apenas altero a cor do problema

Comment: Ah sim, entendi! Você está utilizando o bootstrap ou algo para te auxiliar com o design da pagina? pode fazer a alteração com código in-line por JS... Seria interessante ter algum código que coloque automaticamente uma cor que de contraste com o fundo. De uma procurada no google, provavelmente já fizeram algo parecido!

Answer (score 0):

## RESPOSTA EDITADA

Bem acredito que a maioria das coisas visuais que você esteja enfrentando possam ser resolvidas com CSS e alguns tratamentos.
Por exemplo quando o usuário mudar para o BackGround escuro chamar alguma class que mudasse a formatação dos inputs de dados, dentro dessa class (no CSS) todos elementos devem ter o

```
!important
```

pois esse comando vai ignorar regras antigas e executar por cima delas por exemplo meu código tem comando de *Style inline* no HTML e meu CSS tem o !important olhe o resultado:

```js
    function changeclass() {

    var NAME = document.getElementById("change")

    NAME.classList.toggle('bgEscuro');

    }
```

```css
    .bgEscuro {
        background-color: black !important;
        color: grey !important;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 id="change" style="background-color: white; color: black">Hello World!</h1>

    <button type="button" onClick="changeclass()">Click Me!</button>


    </body>
    </html>
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-customize-my-site-with-profiles-and-themes

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css

Comment: Não consigo alterar por css porque as cores estão como estilo inline, que tem maior prioridade do que definidos em classes CSS

Comment: e não há uma função javascript que troca a cor, a folha de estilo inteira é alterada para a que contém o tema correspondente

Comment: Bem eu acredito que você possa colocar assim no CSS então .bgEscuro {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: grey !important;
} 

Colocando o !important ele ignora todo e qualquer outro código mesmo que inline e executa com prioridade o codigo com !important

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta colocando style inline e o css com !important para você ver

Comment: @Pilati resposta editada pode conferir agora